# Replace last numbers from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string url with following structure:

> url/inbox/g/{page_number}

I am in a situation where I need to replace `{page_number}` with a new value. So I need somehow to search for `url/inbox/g` and replace it with `url/inbox/g/{new_value}`.

How to use `replace()` function to achieve this?

Comment: is `{page_number}` the literal string "{page_number}" or is it an actual number? Also, when you say you need to search for `url/inbox/g` where are you searching for that? Is there a larger text where you need find all mentions of a URL and replace them, or is it just the URL itself you get as input?

Comment: @vlaz it is an actual number. by search, i mean the first parameter of `replace` function. thank you

Comment: Have you considered a RegEx?

Comment: @PM77-1, yes this seems to be the only solution since page_number is dynamic. I just don't know how to

Comment: You can also use `.split()` to split up the URL at `/` characters, replace the last element of the array, then join them back with `.join()`. These are all simple operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the number is the last portion of the string, you may use non regex solution using `lastIndexOf` and `slice`:

```
<script>
  url = 'url/inbox/g/44';
  replaceNumStr = 'Dummy';
  newVal = url.slice(0,url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  alert(newVal+replaceNumStr);
 </script>
```

Checkout [this demo](http://jsbin.com/kuwepirare/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "url/inbox/g/4321"
var your_number = 1234
url = url.replace(/\d+$/, your_number)
```

Comment: that's not going to work because {page_number} is going to be a number which changes each time so it can't be hardcoded into the `replace` function call

Comment: the value of `page_number` is rendered served side, I don't have control of it. It can be 1 digit or more

Comment: right, totally misread the question.  my bad.  that regex should be what you're looking for in my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a replace statement like this:

```
var newVal  = 'anything',
    pattern = "/url\/inbox\/g\/\d+$/",
    reg     = new RegExp(pattern, "i");
    repURL  = url.replace(reg, "url/inbox/g/" + newVal);
```

I am assuming `url` is dynamically accessed.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use your RegExp and feedback, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following regular expression : `/\/\d*$/m` And the replacement could be done with :

```
str.replace(/\/\d*$/m, "/" + n)
```

Where `n` is the new value

The regular expression says *find everything that match "/" followed by 0 or more digits and which end the string*. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use your RegExp and feedback, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two other possibilities, not using RegExp.

```js
const url = 'url/inbox/g/{page_number}';
const parts = url.split('/', 3);
const new_number = '{new_page_number}';
parts.push(new_number);
const new_url1 = parts.join('/');
console.log(new_url1);
```

```js
const url = 'url/inbox/g/{page_number}';
const new_number = '{new_page_number}';
const new_url2 = `${url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'))}/${new_number}`;
console.log(new_url2);
```